# Master/Slave Mysql Architecture vs Server/Read DB and Separate DB for writes only

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, database-cluster

What are the advantages and disadvantages for Master/Slave type mysql architectures vs load balancing web servers with read only db's in each using a separate server holding a mysql database just for the writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master/Slave type architecture is useful for when your application is "read heavy", that is a majority of connections to the database are for reading data as opposed to writing data.

Master/Slave allows you to scale out your application just by adding more hardware. Simply create a copy of the database on a new box and add it as a slave to the master.

With regards to

> load balancing web servers with read
>   only db's in each using a separate
>   server holding a mysql database just
>   for the writes?

This just sounds like a Master/Slave type architecture. With Master/Slave you want the slaves to be read only, as the master is the only place where data changes (and those changes propagate to the slaves).

Comment: so is it better to have the master & slaves on separate servers and the web servers separate as well OR regarding my second setup option ... adding a db server to the web servers as I role out new web servers that are load balanced and the master is on its own server? Will performance be an issue with either... will it be more costly depending on the architecture I choose?

Comment: Yes definitely have the master & slaves on different servers - there is no point having them on the same server as you can't scale on just one server. There is no problem having database slaves on the web servers, and this will probably save you money but later on you may want to have dedicated database slave servers without web servers running on them.